# Access Denied on SQL tab when trying to use AD security in Opserver website

Tags: iis-7, opserver

I was using the `alladmin` option in `SecuritySettings.config`, and had setup up `Dahsboard.json` and `SQLSettings.json` to give me everything that I need.

I have since changed my `SecuritySettings.config` to read as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SecuritySettings provider="ad" />
```

And I have also updated my `Web.config` file:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SiteName" value="Status" />
    <add key="SiteNameLong" value="Network Status" />
    <add key="Profiling" value="local" />
    <add key="PollerProfiling" value="true" />
    <add key="ViewGroups" value="myloginname" />
    <add key="AdminGroups" value="myloginname" />
  </appSettings>
```

When I navigate to my server running opserver, I get the message:

> "Uh no! No Configuration found!"

However, when I navigate to `op-server/dashboard` I can see the dashboard and click through on the links. But I don't have the usual links to Dashboard and SQL on the top right.
When I navigate straight to `op-server/sql/servers` I just get the big red padlock and the message

> "Access Denied"

On the page `op-server/about` I can see the following under security:
[image: Security Enabled, Current user blank, Request IP 127.0.0.1, Current Roles Authenticated, Admins DOMAIN_NAME\groupname, Viewers DOMAIN_NAME\groupname]

Is there something else that I'm missing in the configuration files? Or have I missed something when I've configured IIS? I've never used IIS before, so I have no idea if I've missed something when setting it up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I went through the code and found this

```
    public ActiveDirectoryProvider(SecuritySettings settings)
    {
        if (settings.Server.HasValue()) Servers = settings.Server.Split(StringSplits.Comma_SemiColon).ToList();
        AuthUser = settings.AuthUser;
        AuthPassword = settings.AuthPassword;
    }
```

It is undocumented but it looks for a user and passwords in the settings. My understanding is that it is used to authenticate in AD to check the logging in users credentials.

After setting those in the config file AD authentication worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting confused by the

> "Uh no! No Configuration found!"

Turns out it's because I signed in with `user.name@domain.com` and the application only checks for `user.name`